# How do I undo a partial git stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

I had a dirty working directory and used `git stash save -p` to selectively stash some of the changes. My intention is splitting what used to be a big commit into two smaller commits. The problem now is that I accidentally stashed the wrong thunks so I want to do it again. I tried doing a `git stash pop`, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827160/undo-a-git-stash) but doing that gives me this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    my_file.js
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, the following was enough:

```
% git add myfile.js
% git stash pop
% git reset myfile.js
```

Alternatively, commit myfile.js, then pop the stash, resolving any conflicts. To get rid of the dummy commit, `git reset --soft HEAD^`. Something like:

```
% git add myfile.js
% git commit
% git stash pop
    # resolve conflicts if needed
% git reset --soft HEAD^
```

`--soft` means don't touch the working tree or index; `HEAD^` means the commit just before the last one.

The manual actually mentions this behavior, though I've never noticed it until now:

> ```
> pop [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
> ```
>
> Remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it on top of the current working tree state, i.e., do the inverse operation of `git stash save`. **The working directory must match the index.**

*(emphasis mine)* When we do `git add`, we're causing the index and working directory to match (they both contain the change that wasn't stashed). Similarly, when we create a commit, they match. (they both contain no changes)