# How to undo stashing on git?

Tags: git, github

I just stashed before committing on git. I need help with reverting back because it looks like I have lost my changes. 
I'm using git bash.

Comment: `git stash pop` will re-apply your last stashed changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo a git stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827160/undo-a-git-stash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git stash pop` or `git stash apply` + `git stash drop` (after having confirmed the stash pop got all your changes back).

Answer (score 0):

Just run

> **git stash pop**

This will un-stash your changes